# Why should I need setRetainInstance or onSaveInstance if I can use android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenLayout"

Tags: android, fragment

Why should I need to use `setRetainInstance()` or `onSaveInstance()` to save state and I can use `android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenLayout"` and get the samething *"saving state non-UI state"*? I mean with less headache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `android:configChanges`. It will break things in subtle ways and will prevent Android from getting the proper layout/theme/dimensions, etc. for the current configuration.

`onSaveInstanceState()` is completely orthogonal to this: you need to save state so you can restore it if Android kills your process to save memory. `configChagnes` only prevents it from re-creating the activity on rotation, keyboard state changes, etc.

`setRetainInstance()` is for fragments that you don't want re-created on device rotation, etc. If you don't call it, Android will serialize their state in a Bundle, and re-create them along with the parent activity.

In short, while `configChanges` appears to be a 'shortcut' it is not. Don't rely on it and save/restore state as necessary using the proper tools for each case.

Comment: one thing , why google put  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and onSaveInstanceState(). what the difference between them , if i can retain any object in onSaveInstance why onRetainNonConfigurationInstance exist

Comment: You should really read the documentation, it has enough details. In short, `onSaveInstanceState()` will serialize things in a `Bundle`, while you can return a 'live' instance  from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` such as a thread, or even an activity. Documentation is in the usual place: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()