# Should all activities be modeled as fragments?

Tags: android, configuration, android-fragments

A frequently asked question is "*how do you maintain your activity's state between configuration changes?*".

Answers to this question seem largely dependent upon the developer's preference. However, one thing does appear certain - refrain from using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the Manifest file (see [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822367/1501327)).

Therefore, to ensure stability we ought to retain an object during configuration change as suggested by android (see [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)). However, this requires the use of `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` that has been deprecated in API 13; instead it suggests that we use `setRetainInstance` of the `Fragment` class.

Given this preference by Android for fragments, should we now be designing our activities where the main UI is itself a fragment, and the activity just serves as a 'driver' or 'fragment manager' for the 'main fragment' and any possible 'fragment children' it may have?

In addition, am I right in thinking that setting `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest file is actually okay providing you're using the same resources for both landscape and portrait views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore, to ensure stability we ought to retain an object during configuration change as suggested by android

That is the second-tier solution. Where possible, simply contribute to the instance state `Bundle` (e.g., `onSaveInstanceState()` in your activity or fragment). Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` or a retained fragment where you have instance state that cannot be stored in a `Bundle`.

> should we now be designing our activities where the main UI is itself a fragment, and the activity just serves as a 'driver' or 'fragment manager' for the 'main fragment' and any possible 'fragment children' it may have?

You are certainly welcome to design your UI that way if you wish.

> am I right in thinking that setting android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in the manifest file is actually okay providing you're using the same resources for both landscape and portrait views?

No, insofar as your app will then break for every other configuration change (locale change, SIM card change, keyboard change, etc.). If you use `android:configChanges`, usually you need to handle *all* configuration changes that way.

Comment: Great answer! Okay, so if your activity had a number of `View` objects which you alter at run time (e.g. text colour) and you want to save those alterations through a configuration change, would it be better to save the state of all those View objects in an instance state `Bundle`, or do the UI in a fragment and makes use of `setRetainInstance`?

Comment: @JamesB: I would use the instance state `Bundle`. It is no more work than what you would have with the retained fragment, and it handles other cases besides configuration change (e.g., user re-visits your app from the recent-tasks list, but Android had terminated your process in the meantime).

Comment: Thanks! So if you want to be sure, use instance state `Bundle`. Got it!